# Django JWT-Auth also i have login API. Can i generate token on login and send to the front-end?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

> I am using **'rest_framework_jwt.authentication'** and also i have Login API, if i am generating token over default **auth-token** API then what is the use of Login API?

so can i generate token while executing login API and if its success then send back generated token to the front-end.

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', views.UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^api/auth/token/', obtain_jwt_token),
```

serializers.py

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
token = CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only= True)
email = EmailField(label='Email Address', allow_blank= True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'token'
    ]

    extra_kwargs = {"password":
                        {"write_only": True}
                        }

def validate(self, data):
    user_obj = None
    email = data.get("email", None)
    password = data["password"]
    if not email:
        raise ValidationError('A username or email is required to login')
    user = User.objects.filter(
            Q(email=email) 
        ).distinct()
    if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
        user_obj = user.first()
    else:
        raise ValidationError("this email is not valid")

    if user_obj:
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError("incorrect creadeintial try again") 
    data["token"] = "SOME BLANK TOKEN"
    return data
```

view.py

```
class UserLoginAPIView(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        new_data = serializer.data
        return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one login API, so pick if you want to write your own or use a provided one. If all you want is to return the token, just use the provided one. But you may want to do other stuff in a custom login. For example, you could also return more information about the user (e.g. the avatar).

It makes a lot of sense to return the token on login, so you just have to return that with

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

def get_jwt_token(user):
    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
    return jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

And then you can get the JWT token like this

```
data["token"] = get_jwt_token(request.user)
```

But I personally don't believe it is best to do this from the serializer validator. Here is how I implement my own login function:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

class APILoginViewSet(APIView):
  """
  Returns user info and tokens if successful
  """

  @csrf_exempt
  def post(self, request, format=None):
    """
    Secondary login method. Uses email and password
    Recommendation: Use `POST:/api/v1/auth/api-jwt-auth/` instead
    """
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = LoginCustomSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        email = serializer.data.get('email')
        password = serializer.data.get('password')

        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
          return Response('Already Logged-in', status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
          if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)

            serialized = UserSerializer(user)
            data = serialized.data

            # Also return JWT token
            data['jwt'] = get_jwt_token(user)

            return Response(data)
          else:
            return Response('This user is not Active.', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        else:
          return Response('Username/password combination invalid.', status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The code above assumes you have a `UserSerializer` and `LoginCustomSerializer`, which could be as simple as:

```
class LoginCustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=200)
  password = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'name')
    read_only_fields = ( 'email', 'username', 'created_at' )
```

Comment: but may i know, why did you used  @csrf_exempt there?

Comment: Because the login should be the one API that you need to allow anybody to access without a token. Later the tokens act as some sort of CSRF

Comment: how can i verify over the views?

Answer (score 0):

Calling API directly from web front-end is not a good idea. You don't need any tokens if you are already logged in using session. In most cases, there is a webserver which calls the api server. The API server authenticates the user with token. The token is stored in the web server's session table. Android or IOS apps can directly call the API and get the token.